# Angular Route Guards: Or vs. And

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, roles, angular-route-guards

I'm working on securing the front-end of my Angular application using route guards. In working with them in the past and researching online, adding multiple guards to a route requires *all* of them to return true to allow access.

But what if I want *just one* to return true to allow access? *(like || instead of &&)*

For example, my route guards look for certain roles in the user's token:

```
@Injectable()
export class ActiveRoleGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private sessionService: SessionService, private router: Router) { }


    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let token = this.sessionService.getToken();

        if (!token) {
             return false;
        }

        if (token.role.toLowerCase().indexOf("active") < 0) {
            this.router.navigate(["/issue"]);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

*And*

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminRoleGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private sessionService: SessionService, private router: Router) { }


    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let token = this.appSessionService.getToken();

        if (!token) {
            return false;
        }

        if (token.role.toLowerCase().indexOf("admin") < 0) {
            this.router.navigate(["/issue"]);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

If I was to combine them normally in a router module it would be something like...

`{path: "someroute", component: SomeComponent, canActivate: [ActiveRouteGuard, AdminRouteGuard]}`

... but that would require a user to be both `Active` and an `Admin`. But what if I wanted to enforce being `Active` and *either* an `Admin` *or* a `Manager`?

It's simple to enforce on the API *like so:*

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Active")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Manager")]
public class SomeController : ApiController
```

but how do I do this in Angular?

Comment: You could do a single guard that would manage both cases, even though it's not that clean, I don't see any other solution yet...
That said, it seems pretty weird for an admin not to have some token check as well. You could fix that by adding an `admin` role to your tokens

Comment: I'd rather not combine because there's currently 6 roles with overlapping permissions. But if this isn't supported in Angular yet then that's my best option

Answer (score 9):

Rather than having two separate `CanActivate` implementations, you could just use a single version that can be "configured". To do this, you can take advantage of the `data` property of [`Route`](https://angular.io/api/router/Route). For example, in your routes, you could do something like:

```
{
    path: "someroute",
    component: SomeComponent,
    canActivate: [RoleRouteGuard],
    data: {
        requiredRoles: ["Role1", "Role2", "Role3"]
    }
}
```

Using this, you could take one of your existing `CanActivate` implementations, and make it more generic. You can access the `requiredRoles` property from `data` via the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`. e.g:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    const requiredRoles = route.data.requiredRoles;
    ....
```

Once you've got this, you can check if the token's role is in the array, etc, etc.

If you have an always-required `Active` role and then a one-of `Admin` or `Manager` role, you could also extend this to have multiple `data` properties. For example, you could have `requiredRoles` and `atLeastOneOfRoles` and update your logic to process that accordingly... There are many options at this point but I don't think you will need help with that.

Comment: Creative solution, I don't love having to pass so many string literals in different places in case these roles change or are renamed. Otherwise, it's an interesting solution.

Comment: @NathanFoss you can use enums in this case.